# Is it possible to use long string in conditional statement only once (without creation additional variable)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, conditional-statements

Here is the thing: I'm getting very long hardcoded string and I have to check the length of this string using a conditional statement and if the statement is `True`, I have to assign that string to `variable`.

So, I'm going to achieve something like:

```
variable = 'VERY_LONG_STRING' if len('VERY_LONG_STRING') > 1000 else "TINY_STRING"
```

Is it even possible?

**UPDATE**
I have to add some explanation - as you can see there is 'VERY_LONG_STRING' two times. And I would like to ask how to use it only once?

**UPDATE2**
It have to be one-liner.

PS
It's for testing purpose only and I have to make it for many times. My script already contain a lot of variables and I'm almost lost in them. So, I would like to avoid some unnecessary use of temporary variables.

Comment: remove the colon `:`?

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is asking if there's a way to do it without having to hard-code `'VERY_LONG_STRING'` twice.

Comment: There *are* ways to do this without hard-coding the string twice, for example: `variable = next((s for s in ['VERY_LONG_STRING'] if len(s) > 1000), 'TINY_STRING')`. So yeah, don't do that. Why are you trying to avoid using another variable anyway?

Comment: @Aran-Fey It's for testing purpose only and I have to make it multiple times. My script already contain a lot of variables and I'm almost lost in them. So, I would like to avoid some unnecessary use of temporary variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variable = "VERY_LONG_STRING"
if len(variable) < 1000:
    variable = "TINY_STRING"
```

Comment: @AK47 Probably not, because I need to do that in one line. As I mentioned earlier It's for testing purpose only and I have to make it multiple times. My script already contain a lot of variables and I'm almost lost in them. So, I would like to avoid some unnecessary use of temporary variables.

Comment: Why does it need to be done in one line ? It's better to write clean and understandable code than to just squash everything into one line ? this solution here is clean and readable

Answer (score 2):

If you want to condense the amount of times you use the hardcoded string, then assign it to a variable:

```
LONG_STRING = 'VERY_LONG_STRING'
TINY_STRING = 'TINY_STRING'
variable = LONG_STRING if len(LONG_STRING) > 1000 else TINY_STRING
print(variable)
>> TINY_STRING
```

Comment: I'm sorry AK47, I have to add some additional explanation to this, as you can see - there is twice 'VERY_LONG_STRING' and I'm asking if its possible to use it only once ?

Comment: Assign it to a variable ?

Comment: Yes it have to be assigned to a variable